# Should I return the value of Collections.addAll() in my methods?

Tags: java, collections

I have a class that contains a `Set<String>` (which is supposed to be a set of tags), and a method to add elements to it (`addTags(String... tagsToAdd)`). Inside the `addTags()` method is a call to `Collections.addAll()`, which has a `boolean` return type. Should my method return it as well?

```
class SomethingWithTags() {
    private Set<String> tags;

    public boolean addTags(String... tagsToAdd) {
        return Collections.addAll(tags, tagsToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on whether the caller of your method would find it useful to know if `addAll` modified the set of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would return the `boolean` value.

If you need it (say for using `addTags()` in a `if` clause), you can use it. Otherwise, you can just ignore the return value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you would like to do, that return boolean is identifying If the given `Collections.addAll(c)` changed the collection(c) you passed in as a result.

For more information, have a look at;
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)

Answer (score -1):

For a simple notification that your Collection was modified you could use the boolean type. In more complex software it would be useful to use a listener / observer that reacts on changes of your collection. Also you could write your own one. Therefore, the return value would be useful.

If you just want to add values to the set and let them computed in another component or something like that, you should resign the return value.